# Vectors and triangles

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis

ok so the question says: given triangle $ABC$ and a point $D$ defined by: 
$$\vec{AD}= 3 \vec{AC} + \tfrac{1}{2}\vec{CB}$$
Draw the figure and prove that vector
$$\vec{BD} = -2\vec{BA} + \tfrac{5}{2}\vec{BC}$$

Comment: Have you drawn the figure?

Answer (score 2):

We have

$
\begin{align*}
\overrightarrow{BD} & = \overrightarrow{BA}+\overrightarrow{AD} \\
& = \overrightarrow{BA}+3 \overrightarrow{AC}+\dfrac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{CB} \\
& = \overrightarrow{BA}+3 \left( \overrightarrow{BC}-\overrightarrow{BA} \right)-
\dfrac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{BC} \\
& = -2\overrightarrow{BA}+\dfrac{5}{2}\overrightarrow{BC}.
\end{align*}
$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use that $\vec{AX}=\vec{AB}+\vec{BX}$ for any point $X$.

With this you can fix one of these points, say $A$ and start every vector from there. FDor example you can write  $\vec{CB}=\vec{CA}+\vec{AB} = -\vec{AC}+\vec{AB}$

Comment: In the case of this proble, its leading me to a dead end!